# How to get Excel formula in C # using OleDb?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I need to get the formula contained in an Excel cell. I'm using OleDb to access the spreadsheet, would you like to know if you have how to use it to access a formula in a cell?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. Alternatively though you could use Microsoft Excel Interop library to access the workbook.

Comment: The ACE provider can only access data, it makes no attempt to expose any info about the spreadsheet cell content.  Its object model isn't sophisticated enough to get close.  Several ways to get ahead, the OpenXML wrapper libraries are pretty popular and don't have a lot of over-byte, I see ClosedXML mentioned a lot.